# An Enigmatic Puzzle With a Strange Loop

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

Aesop Fables
-1 ¬engine ¬Greek
10-20
bankrupt louise
input: 10-28 loop victim
st = new String(out); st = StringBuffer(st).insert(1,"M").toString();
The life and times of 
41st 
Return (10-28)

CLARIFICATION: -1 is "minus one"

Hint

> A MUCH MUCH better title would be Gratifying Enigmatic Brainteaser

Hint

> Listen to some music https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KYouXtuk0T8

Hint

> -1 is a locational clue

Comment: Is "41th" (not "41st") deliberate? [EDITED to add:] ... ah, apparently not.

Comment: No it isn't. I changed it. Thanks for telling me,

Comment: Oh, and it is deliberate that the title says "A Enigmatic ..." rather than "An Enigmatic ..."?

Comment: Nope, me being stupid again, but for the future if I have more spelling mistakes its not deliberate (I think there are probably more)

Comment: I don't see anything else here that looks misspelled. I never like to take for granted that such things are mistakes, because sometimes they are deliberate hints or even critical parts of the puzzle.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer**

The first hint:

> The Gratifying Enigmatic Brainteaser referenced in the first hint points to Douglas Hofstadter's book [*Gödel, Escher, Bach*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del,_Escher,_Bach), which is sometimes called *GEB*.

The second hint:

> The linked music is from Bach's [*The Musical Offering*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Musical_Offering), a collection of keyboard pieces. This may just be a hint to help one see the connection to *GEB*. After all, *GEB* opens with a discussion of a piece from the same collection.

There is a hint in the title:

> The strange loop referenced in the title is an allusion to Hofstadter's concept of the [same name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strange_loop), which is discussed in *GEB*.

---

Aesop Fables

> *GEB* includes many dialogues between Achilles and the Tortoise.

-1 ¬engine ¬Greek

> -1 may refer to the introduction of *GEB*, which appears before Chapter 1. In it there is reference to both the ancient Greeks (p. 19) as well as Babbage's dream of an Analytical Engine (pp. 24-25). Not sure what to make of the logical negations.

10-20 bankrupt louise

input: 10-28 loop victim

st = new String(out); st = StringBuffer(st).insert(1,"M").toString();

> Java code to insert 'M' into a string after the first letter. (This may be a reference to the toy formal language [MIU](http://planetmath.org/hofstadtersmiusystem) presented in *GEB*, but I doubt it since the Java code is inconsistent with the syntactic rules of the language.)

The life and times of

41st

> This may refer to the 41st figure in *GEB*:
>
>  [image]

Return (10-28)

Comment: Everything is correct aside from "The life and times of" and "41st"

Comment: Your getting a bit ahead of yourself clue-wise

Comment: -1 Doesn't refer to the prologue, similar though think of prev.